# Android widget design questions

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm creating a widget for the Android platform., however I need some advice on certain aspects.

1) If I have a 3x3 widget, what is the actual dip/dp for this layout?
2) I'm creating a basic calculator layout inside the widget, how can I better layout the elements? **Linear/Absolute/Relative?**
3) Depending on the layout above, are there any examples showing how to better position the elements I want to draw?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) On the android dev website: 
[Widget Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#sizesBlockquote)

> Cells   Pixels

4x1 320x100

3x3 240x300

2x2 160x200

2) [Linear](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html)

3) LinearLayout is very simple to use. Have a vertical linear layout with several horizontal linear layouts as the rows, which contain several button elements.

Comment: Oh I see the NNNxNNN refers to the dp (Y)

In regards to Q3, how do I place the buttons next to each other?

Comment: LinearLayout has an option for orientation (android:orientation="horizontal"), all items inside the layout will be arranged horizontally (so next to each other) and if you use vertical then they will be arranged vertically. So if you want both you nest horizontal layouts inside the vertical layouts. Hope that makes sense, if not please visit the link I gave in 2. for a simple tutorial.